# SharePoint 2013: Update sites based on old Site Template

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, site, template, update

Im currently facing a rather complex issue. A few weeks ago i created an test site, and put a major functionality into a list. The list contains documents(templates) defined as content types, which users can call from the "new" button in the ribbon. The list is called "documents".

I saved the list as a template and created sites based on that particular list template. Speaking right now there are about 10 sites build on this list template.

I decided to add more document templates to the test site to test them out. Once they are functional, i want to distribute these document templates to the active sites. This means i have to somehow distribute the new changes on the test site to all the other sites based on the old Site template.

Question is, how do i do this?